# GCC warning: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE

Tags: c++, gcc

I am working on a small C++ project.
After a while my code started producing the following warnings when compiled and run in debug mode:

```
BFD: warning: /root/Projects/TestProject: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0000002
BFD: warning: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0000002
BFD: warning: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0000002
BFD: warning: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0000002
```

I am not sure why these warnings show up or what exactly they mean. **The application seems to run fine even with these errors. Is there any information about these warnings?**

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and the used GCC version is gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04). The project needs to be run as root for user (if that might matter.)

I am using the __builtin_popcount function somewhere in my code. I noticed that by commenting the line of code containing this function 1 warning disappears:

```
BFD: warning: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1: unsupported GNU_PROPERTY_TYPE (5) type: 0xc0000002
```

The project is compiled with the following commands:

```
/usr/bin/c++    -g   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c /root/Projects/TestProject/src/main.cpp

/usr/bin/c++    -g   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/file1.cpp.o -c /root/Projects/TestProject/src/file1.cpp

/usr/bin/c++    -g   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/file2.cpp.o -c /root/Projects/TestProject/src/file2.cpp

/usr/bin/c++  -g   CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/file1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/file2.cpp.o   -o TestApplication
```

ld version:

```
$ ld.bfd -v
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34
```

Edit:

Tried linking with gold

```
/usr/bin/c++ -fuse-ld=gold -g   CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/file1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/project.dir/src/file2.cpp.o   -o TestApplication
```

This produces the same warnings. No extra information is given.

gold version:

```
$ gold -v
GNU gold (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu 2.34) 1.16
```

Comment: Linking your code with a different linker, such as `lld` or `gold`, instead of the default `ld.bfd` might give you a better insight on what is happening with your code. In order to get the compiler to link using a different linker, try invoking `gcc` or `clang` with `-fuse-ld=lld` or `-fuse-ld=gold`

Comment: Also, it might help knowing what version of `ld.bfd` you are using. In my experience these kinds of warning start to happen when the linker is too old.

Comment: Added ld version and tested with gold linker. Same results...

Comment: Check if you are mixing libraries built with different versions of compiler

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this compilation warning because I installed binutils-2.38 from the source code. It replaces files under /usr/local/bin, such as ld. When I rolled back to binutils-2.30, the problem was solved. BTW, my system is Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using:

```
sudo apt install cmake
```